# Selenium webdriver ruby version assert and verify

Tags: ruby, selenium, webdriver

Is there some method to use for Assert and Verify.

I can't find any for Ruby

Comment: Can you please be more specific in your question - are you trying to write an integration test? Maybe you need a tool such as webrat or capybara?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

1)Assert

```
assert(@driver.find_element(:tag_name => "body").text.include?("Name"),"Page contains the text NAME")
```

2) verify

```
verify { assert(@driver.find_element(:tag_name => "body").text.include?("Name"),"Page contains the text NAME")}
```

Comment: what is the difference between these two statements?

Comment: if the first one fails, the script exits, while if the second one fails, the script will still continue running, and display all the verify fails in the end.

Comment: but even verify block also has an assert inside it isn't it? then the application wont exit?